# Connect to SQL Anywhere - dblgen12.dll not found

Tags: c#, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

I try to connect to a SQL Anywhere 12 database with the iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.v4.0.dll.

On the database server this connection is successful, however on any other PC's I get the error `Language Ressourcefile not found<dblgde12.dll, dblgen12.dll>`.

Orginal (german) error message here, unfortunately even on my english system the error message is in german. 
 [image]

I have found these files on the installation directory of the sql server, but I don't know what to do with them, since I can't install them in the gac.

The Connection:

```
iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection connection = new SAConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = new SAConnectionStringBuilder(){  DatabaseName = "123", UserID = "123", Password =
                    "123", ServerName = "123" , Host = "10.11.11.10"}.ConnectionString;
connection.Open();
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show your work to create a connection and exception message as a text, preferring in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more time asking google I found the following question asked:
http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/19449/cannot-find-the-language-resource-file-dblgen12dll

The accepted answer links to http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbadmin/da-install-s-5107108.html, where is explained where the dll looks for the files.

> On Windows, SQL Anywhere searches the following paths relative to each
> location in the preceding list:
>
> .
>
> ..
>
> .\bin32 and ..\bin32 (32-bit programs only)
>
> .\bin64 and ..\bin64 (64-bit programs only)
>
> .\java (for Java-related files)
>
> ..\java (for Java-related files)
>
> .\scripts (for SQL script files)
>
> ..\scripts (for SQL script files)

The necessary files can be found here http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbprogramming/deploying-adonet-deploy.html

All these files can be found on a SQL Anywhere Installation 12 in the following directory: *C:\Program Files\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 12*

Answer (score 1):

Extra info

You need to put `dblgde12.dll` and `dblgen12.dll` in the project folder `\bin\debug`

As for the connection string i'm using this one.

```
SAConnection conn = new SAConnection("ENG=LXDBSRV;DBN=database;UID=username;PWD=password;POOLING =FALSE;LINKS=tcpip{Host=PC-g};CS=utf-8");
```

Other way is :

```
SAConnection conn = new SAConnection("DSN=LXSYDSN;UID=username;PWD=password;DBF=c:\\LxOffice.db");
```